# Spring MVC debug A to Z

Tags: java, spring, debugging, spring-mvc

**BEFORE START**

Let's say I put a debug point like below~!

```
  @RequestMapping("/test")
  public String test() {
      String char = "abcdEFGhIjQlmnopqrstuvwXYZ";

●     char.toLowerCase(); // pointed here.
  }
```

And what's inside of `String` class... ( this is an actual code snippet inside of String class )

```
.
.
.
public String toLowerCase()
{
    return toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
}
.
.
.
```

**WHAT I WANT TO DO HERE**

is that when debugging, pressing F5 (step into) on the debug point above takes me to the `toLowerCase()` method in `String` class. Currently in my development environment, this doesn't happen.

**AND I WANT TO**

hang on to these processes below and check every steps and inspect everything so that I can fully understand what's going on inside in Spring MVC application. Well I've read many docs about, so to speak, core classes of Spring MVC and studied its architecture. But what I can do by the efforts now is just to imagine what the proccesses would be like.

[image]

**Time to make it concrete.**

Is there any special configurations to do this?

Comment: I usually develop in eclipse and i'm still using maven as project manager, and maven allows me to download the source for the dependencies i'm debugging, and i actually can insert breakpoints in that source code, resume execution and get it to stop on the new breakpoints.

Comment: @SalvadorJuanMartinez I used to use maven on my project but I got rid of it to develop my app with no internet connection ( or at least internal network)... well, come to think about it, debugging used to work as I intended. I've just found out that maven made that happen :[. thank you for the knowledge.

Comment: If working offline without maven is a requirement for you, being able to still debug these is possible i think, but need to previously download all the source code of your dependencies, and have them set as a project in your IDE and then link them as dependencies of your actual project.  It is a lot of work and headaches, but is the only solution i can think of right now.

Comment: @SalvadorJuanMartinez I have all the `jar`s required to run the whole stuff in Spring MVC, but isn't that enough?

Comment: jars usually only contain bytecode, there is no information of the source code, like  how the code is distributed in different lines and in what line is each sentence, which is required if you wanna insert a breakpoint in a certain line number.

Answer (score 0):

I would put a breakpoint in one of my controller methods. Then I would "invoke" that method by a HTTP Request (from my browser).

Then I would inspect the stack trace *(you can click on the stacktrace lines to jump to the implementation and also inspect the variables)* or I would use "Step Return" (F7) to understand how the controller method is invoked.

This technique would not show you all the actions and additional stuff that is done before your controller method is invoked, but it would show you a straight line of invocations that end in your controller method.